# An unknown error prompts after adding a reference to a dll

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0

I tried to add a reference to my application.

[image]

Then after I rebuilded the solution and about to view the form designer, the below error always pops up:

[image]

I tried to remove again the reference but It seems the form designer is not working properly. Some controls are not properly displayed. How can I solve this?

[image]

**** **By the way, this error promts whe I switch to form designer view of my IDE**

Comment: Examine your `InitializeComponent` method..there must be a runtime error in there at some line..

Comment: the application runs without error. It is just the form designer not working....

Comment: Judging by the stacktrace you are using sharpdevelop?

Comment: By the way, this error promts whe I switch to form designer view of my IDE

Comment: I don't know sharpdevelop that well, but this reference: http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/p/13059/35346.aspx  , suggests editing the .csproj file manually to set the versionminor of the office reference. (or removing the reference completely if you don't need it anymore)

Comment: I also suspect that this issue is only because of my IDE. I will try to load the solution using Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

I just Cleaned, and Rebuilded the solution. Now it's working : )